# Unicode ICU4C issue about conversion between UTF16 and WCS (OS-X only)

Tags: macos, unicode, globalization, icu

I use ICU4C in a C++ software builded under Windows, Linux and Mac-OSX.
I have an issue ONLY under Mac-OSX, and only related to conversion between UTF16 and WCS (calling  u_strToWCS ).
Simply the unicoded chars are replaced with a fixed char.

The ICU4C version doesn't matter: i try the lastest yesterday.

My Mac OS-X is 10.6.6 (Snow Leopard), GCC: i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1.

I also try to switch between shared libraries and static libraries, without any changes.

I reproduce the issue with the code below. Look the variables "c1", "c2" and "c3": Windows and Linux give the same result, Mac OS-X not (my issue).

I don't understand if is a compilation problem, or icu bug, or whatelse.

I hope anyone can suggest to me a direction, or at least confirm my test results.

Thanks.

```
    // Manually construct UTF16 buffer of this string: http://pastebin.com/HW06TaA9
    unsigned char* pSource = new unsigned char[28];
    pSource[0] = 84;
    pSource[1] = 0;
    pSource[2] = 101;
    pSource[3] = 0;
    pSource[4] = 115;
    pSource[5] = 0;
    pSource[6] = 116;
    pSource[7] = 0;
    pSource[8] = 32;
    pSource[9] = 0;
    pSource[10] = 179;
    pSource[11] = 111;
    pSource[12] = 128;
    pSource[13] = 149;
    pSource[14] = 121;
    pSource[15] = 114;
    pSource[16] = 43;
    pSource[17] = 82;
    pSource[18] = 76;
    pSource[19] = 136;
    pSource[20] = 63;
    pSource[21] = 101;
    pSource[22] = 64;
    pSource[23] = 83;
    pSource[24] = 125;
    pSource[25] = 0;
    pSource[26] = 0;
    pSource[27] = 0;

    int32_t nChars = 100;
    wchar_t* pDest = new wchar_t[nChars];
    memset(pDest, 0, nChars * sizeof(wchar_t));

    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    u_strToWCS(pDest, nChars, &nChars, (const UChar*) pSource, -1, &status);
    if(U_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        wchar_t c1 = pDest[2];  // Ascii char. Win: 115, Linux: 115, OS-X: 115 
        wchar_t c2 = pDest[5];  // Japan char. Win: 28595, Linux: 28595, OS-X: 26
        wchar_t c3 = pDest[6];   // Japan char. Win: 38272, Linux: 38272, OS-X: 26
    }
```

Comment: This is also filed at http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/8894

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this bug. This had been already fixed in latest ICU and I've included a workaround. https://ssl.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/8894#comment:4